# Is it possible to give public access to files in a folder within wwwroot?

Tags: windows-vista, iis, iis-7

I want to share some files on my computer using IIS within the `wwwroot` folder. I'm currently getting a 403 error when I enter the URL ipaddress/Folder. Is there any way to get rid of the 403 error and allow my computer to make the files public?

Comment: Yes, but to tell you how we need to know what OS (and hence, version of IIS) you're using.

Comment: I'm on IIS7 and windows vista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying "ipaddress/Folder", meaning to list all files in the folder, requires Directory browsing permission for this folder. Directory browsing permission is off by default, as a security measure.

For Vista and above see [Enable or Disable Directory Browsing in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109) .

You do not need this permission for accessing a file via "ipaddress/Folder/file", but you then need to know the file's name in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) if you're on Linux and give read access to all users, I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: IIS is Windows only